# svn - Upgrading working directory says directory is missing \.svn\entries

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have TortoiseSVN installed.  The About dialog says the following:

```
TortoiseSVN 1.7.10, Build 23359 - 64 Bit , 2012/10/08 11:46:26
Subversion 1.7.7, 
apr 1.4.6
apr-utils 1.3.12
neon 0.29.6
OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
zlib 1.2.7
```

I have multiple respositories.

One of them keeps telling me the working working directory needs to be upgraded to **1.7** format. When I click the button to the perform the upgrade, I get an error dialog that it cannot be upgraded because it is not a **pre-1.7** directory and it cannot open the **.svn\entries.**

I've checked the repository out to a new folder multiple times.

It starts out just fine with the happy green check mark.  However, by the next day, the check mark is gone and it wants to upgrade the folder again.

Only this one repository does this. All the others behave very well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your TortoiseSVN client to version 1.8 and see if it helps.

If you checkout a working copy using SVN 1.7 client then the working copy is already in the format understandable by SVN 1.7 client. You may have Subversion 1.8 client installed on your system which upgrades the working copy to version 1.8 format. TortoiseSVN 1.7 will fail to use 1.8-format working copy after the upgrade done with version 1.8 client.

So I recommend to make sure that you don't have Subversion 1.8 client installed on the machine as well; it can be that the SVN 1.8 client upgrades the working copy to 1.8 format thus SVN 1.7 fails to access 1.8-format working copy.

P.S.: It looks like that you are confusing [the working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) and [the repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository) terms here. The misunderstanding can be the root cause so I suggest ensuring that you indeed operate on the working copy, not on the repository.